# How can i use a single function to change the innerHTML of all the buttons in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have 9 buttons in my page. When ever I click on a button the inner HTML of the button should change. How can I achieve this using a single JavaScript function? i.e. What can I do so that the code detects different buttons in the HTML?

```
<html>
<script>
function changeHtml(){
alert("h");                     
element.innerHTML = "y"; /* I tried to achieve this by setting the "element" to "this"
i++                         However I am getting an error innerHTML of null is undefined.*/ 
}
element.onclick = changeHtml;
</script>
<body>
<button id = "but1" ></button>
<button id = "but2" ></button>
<button id = "but3" ></button>
<button id = "but4" ></button>
<button id = "but5" ></button>
<button id = "but6" ></button>
<button id = "but7" ></button>
<button id = "but8" ></button>
<button id = "but9" ></button>
</body>
</html>
```

How should the code be modified so that when ever I click on a button, let it be the first or the sixth button the code should detect the button and therefore call the "changeHtml" function on that button?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/id-html-attribute/

Comment: What do you want to do to these different buttons? What do you mean by "*[detecting] different buttons*"?

Comment: If you want proper help you should post some code or even better make a fiddle.

Comment: And, ideally, post a specific question.

Comment: Sure I will post the code. Thanks for the comments. @DavidThomas When ever I click on a button in my webpage a function should be called and the html of the button should be changed. I have 9 buttons in my web page and I want to achieve the task by using a single function in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get all the buttons and assign a click listener to each of them. To differentiate between them, you can use a custom `data-*` attribute on each button (if you don't want to rely on button's text only). You can access the attribute using the `getAttribute` method, so you can make conditional switches, etc.

See this example:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  var b = buttons[i];
  b.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('button ' + this.getAttribute('data-num') + ' clicked!');
    this.textContent = '-' + this.textContent + '-';
    })
  }
```

```html
<button data-num="1">Button</button>
<button data-num="2">Button</button>
<button data-num="3">Button</button>
<button data-num="CRAZY">Crazy Button</button>
<button data-num="Where's Luigi?">Super Mario Button</button>
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! Now select the answer that helped you the most so we know this is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the buttons and then loop them and assign the HTML you want, where `.button` is the class of each button. If you don't want to depend on classes you may use the tag method `.getElementsByTagName`.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
       this.innerHTML = "Text changed!";
    });
```

If you want one by one, you can do:

```
 var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');

button[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
   this.innerHTML = "I am the first button"
});
```

Comment: @user2713706 Make sure to mark the answer as correct if it helped you.